# Android AlerDialog is showing already?

Tags: android, dialog, alert

How do I prevent an `AlertDialog` from showing if it is already showing? I've searched everywhere and used different solutions to work for my project, However I have a loop that runs every 5 seconds and calls the `AlertDialog` method(`showSettingsAlert()`) and each time a new `AlertDialog` stacks on the previous one.

I want the method to check at the start if it's already showing a dialog.

Here is my code:

```js
public AlertDialog Dialog;
public void showSettingsAlert() {
  if (Dialog != null && Dialog.isShowing()) {
    return;
  } else {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Disabled");

    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to go to location settings menu?");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      @
      Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        context.startActivity(intent);
      }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      @
      Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
      }
    });
    Dialog = alertDialog.create();
    Dialog.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Tell me the reason for the down-voting so I can actually improve my future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it this way,

```
//check dialog open method
public boolean checkDialogOpen()
    {
        if (Dialog!= null && Dialog.isShowing())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

your updated code,

```
public AlertDialog Dialog;

public void showSettingsAlert() {

  if (checkDialogOpen()) 
    return;

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Disabled");

    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to go to location settings menu?");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      @
      Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        context.startActivity(intent);
      }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      @
      Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
      }
    });
    Dialog = alertDialog.create();
    Dialog.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `Dialog` instead of `alertDialog` in `checkDialogOpen` method, because otherwise it's unresolved.

Comment: It says non-static field 'Dialog' cannot be referenced from a static context. I removed static and ran the app but the dialog box is still stacking.

Comment: sorry @SnowTauren please remove static from method.

Comment: It worked by initializing static `Dialog`, the only issue I have now is that the   `Dialog` shows every 5 seconds (maybe I can make a trigger for it) but it does not stack (which was my question). Marked your post as answer :). Thank you!